# 301 redirect images directory

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I've recently deployed a new Wordpress site that was replacing an existing site. So I've set up a whole bunch of 301 redirects in the .htaccess file.

I'm having troubles with one particular redirect though:

```
Redirect 301 /images/‎ http://domain.com/
```

I seem to have no trouble with any other redirects using exactly the same syntax. Could the 'images' directory be some sort of reserved word somehow? Not even sure where to start troubleshooting this!

Any ideas?

Comment: What is it doing that is wrong? What's an example of a URL that isn't working? What are your other redirects?

Comment: Okay, so I figured it out.

There were other redirects, e.g.: Redirect 301 /images/‎other-folder/  http://domain.com/ interfering. Now I've just done: RedirectMatch 301 /images/* http://domain.com/ instead and all good :)